# Local dependencies resolved by SBT but not by Play! Framework

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to use banana-RDF, a locally published library (published using SBT's `publish-local`) from a Play! Framework project, but when running `compile` from Play's console, the wanted library is not resolved, when using `compile` from SBT's console everything goes fine.

I find this behavior pretty weird as Play uses SBT to resolve dependencies. By the way, I'm using the 0.12.3 version of SBT in my Play project.

The error I'm getting when compiling with Play is pretty basic:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.w3#banana_2.10;2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT            
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home_local/.installedSoftware/play-2.1.1/repository/local/org.w3/banana_2.10/2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/w3/banana_2.10/2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT/banana_2.10-2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/org/w3/banana_2.10/2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT/banana_2.10-2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Akka Snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/org/w3/banana_2.10/2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT/banana_2.10-2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== OSS117: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/w3/banana_2.10/2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT/banana_2.10-2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///home_local/.m2/repository/org/w3/banana_2.10/2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT/banana_2.10-2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Local SBT Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///home_local/.ivy2/local/org/w3/banana_2.10/2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT/banana_2.10-2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/w3/banana_2.10/2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT/banana_2.10-2013_02_21-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that SBT's `publish-local` publishes your library to `~/.ivy2/local`, whereas Play seems to have his ivy2 local repository pointer to the ivy2 repository of his own installation folder (your `/home_local/.installedSoftware/play-2.1.1/repository/local`).

You can add for example this resolver to your Play's `Build.scala`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("Local repo", file(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ivy2/local"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Comment: Strangely it doesn't work for me (SBT 0.13). I'm monitoring system file activity and SBT doesn't even try to go to above mentioned folder.